# Full outer join in mysql with multiple condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
table1

id  userid date_t  game  hdigit inside
1   yui    0909    alpha 8      700
2   loi    0809    beta  7      600

table2

id  userid date_t  game  hdigit outside
1   yui    0909    alpha 8       600
2   ron    0809    gama  5      600

I want result like this

id  userid date_t  game  hdigit inside  outside
1   yui    0909    alpha 8      700      600
2   loi    0809    beta  7      600       null
3   ron    0809    gama  5      null      600
```

I have tried simple join

```
select table1.userid 
     , table1.date_t 
     , table1.game
     , table1.inside 
     , table2.outside 
  from table1 
     , table2 
 where table1.hdigit = table2.hdigit 
   AND table1.date_t = table2.date_t 
   AND table2.game = table1.game 
   AND table1.userid = table2.userid
```

Obviously it is giving me the simple join of common values but how to achieve above thing any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: change comma to JOIN. Change JOIN to LEFT JOIN. Change WHERE to  ON.

Comment: I didn't get you @Strawberry

Comment: And note that '3' is meaningless in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purposes, I think `group by`/`union all` is the best approach:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, userid, date_t, game, hdigit,
       max(inside) as inside, max(outside) as outside
from ((select userid, date_t, game, hdigit, inside, null as outside
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select userid, date_t, game, hdigit, null, outside
       from table2
      )
     ) t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
group by userid, date_t, game, hdigit;
```

The reason you don't want `full join` is because you appear to want one row for the four key combination.  When you want one row, `group by` is often the viable solution.